# Trying to display a GeoJSON on Openlayers 3

Tags: gis, openlayers-3, geojson

I am trying to display a geojson file on an openlayers map.  The openlayers map is already working, however I cannot figure out how to display the features from the geojson file.  [The example on their website](http://openlayers.org/en/latest/examples/geojson.html) is unfortunately not very helpful, as it is simply the geojson object being written directly into the file and then accessed later.  I wish to take the features from a separate geojson file and display them on the map.

This is what I have so far, copied directly from the example:

```
var vectorSource = new ol.source.Vector({
    features: (new ol.format.GeoJSON()).readFeatures(geojsonObject)
});

var vectorLayer = new ol.layer.Vector({
    source: vectorSource,
    style: styleFunction
});

var map = new ol.Map({
    layers: [
        new ol.layer.Tile({
            source: new ol.source.OSM()
        }),
        vectorLayer
    ],
    target: 'map',
    controls: ol.control.defaults({
        attributionOptions: /** @type {olx.control.AttributionOptions} */ ({
            collapsible: false
        })
    }),
    view: new ol.View({
        center: [0, 0],
        zoom: 2
    })
```

});

What I need to know is how do I "open" the file and get the features from the geojson file (currently located at the url `..\public\geojson\federal_ridings.geojson`) in place of the variable `geojsonObject` which is already there?

Answer (score 1):

To add GeoJSON layer from external file replace:

```
var vectorSource = new ol.source.Vector({
    features: (new ol.format.GeoJSON()).readFeatures(geojsonObject)
});
```

with

```
var vectorSource = new ol.source.Vector({
    url: '..\public\geojson\federal_ridings.geojson',
    format: new ol.format.GeoJSON()
});
```

[`ol.format.GeoJSON` documentation](http://openlayers.org/en/master/apidoc/ol.format.GeoJSON.html)

> Make sure `federal_ridings.geojson` is a [valid JSON file](http://jsonlint.com/#)

[**Demo**](https://plnkr.co/edit/mLdlJTUxbKnDvxepYKX2?p=preview)